# Office 2013 Com Shim Add-in

Tags: office-2013, comaddin

I have a Com Add-in for Office 07,2010 created in VS 2008 , .net 2.0. implementing IDExensibility2 and IRibbonExtensibility.

Com Shim dll - C++
Rest all code -C#

I need to upgrade this project to Office 2013, i have read online that it doesn't require any change, the same com add-in should work properly for Office 2013.

I created solution files for office 2013 with office15 object library. The build was successful.

But when i deploy dll's and register the Com Add-in , it shows in active Add-ins but there is no log at all. (meaning Office is not even taking it up).

Not even Onconnection() is called.

Is there anything i am missing? Pls help